# How can I create a partitioned table in EF Core?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework, relational-database

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
public class ObjectA
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
   ...etc
}
```

I want to partition by {CreatedOn} and I need to create the table with EF migration. The DB is MSSql.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not. Well, you can by issuing SQL in a migration, but there is no in build support for partitioned tables in EfCore. Which is, among other things, why many people consider EF Migrations to be kind of a sad joke - they cover a lot of what beginners know, but they fall apart the moment you start actually using even the most basic non beginner functions.

Comment: agree with 'EF Migrations to be kind of a sad joke'.

Comment: it gives you the basics and something that is what you want. You don't need to create partitions in each and every table. So just modify the migration script for that particular table. So the solution does carry the flexibility instead of being a joke.

Comment: its a joke if they dont support partitioning in future

Comment: "... sad joke" is a bad critique.  Migrations are inherently a good thing and better than any alternative way managing schema changes.  Whether or not the migration framework supports in-code versions of all SQL queries for all underlying database technologies is pointlessly moot as long as they have support for raw sql.

Comment: Nope. Use migrations on a team i run, look for other work. One has to have very limited experience in larger and controlled applications or work only with smaller data to not see their negatives. Sad joke is a reality.